# J2EE: Spring + Maven + Hibernate integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get spring and hibernate woring in maven project. Here's my various files:

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>local.bb</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenSpringMVC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MavenSpringMVC</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
                MAIN / SPRING
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
                SPRING / HIBERNATE
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
                HIBERNATE / TILES
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-request-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
                TILES / ...
        -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Config.java

```
    package local.bb.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import local.bb.test.Test;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Array;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config {

    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver isvr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        isvr.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
        isvr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        isvr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return isvr;
    }


    @Bean
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dmds = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");
        dmds.setUsername("root");
        return dmds;
    }


    @Bean
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        lsfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lsfb.setPackagesToScan("local.bb.entities");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        lsfb.setHibernateProperties(props);
        return lsfb;
    }
}
```

dispatcher.servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="local.bb.*" />
</beans>
```

If some other files are required to spot my problem I'll paste them. The problem is I get such error when run my app:

```
Exception while loading the app: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in local.bb.config.Config:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)
```

I've been searching on the Internet for ome time and `pom.xml` seems to be ok. I even found (potentially missing) class and method in my dependencies jars structure what makes this error even more odd. Additionally the hibernate configuration is pasted from another project(which is not maven) where it works ok. The controllers are good and views are as well. Does anybody have any ideas?

---

EDIT:

Full stack trace of the error(I had to use pastebin, if there' some better way, let m know. The stack was to big to paste it here): http://pastebin.com/S50Jx3iD

Comment: Post full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try the GA version of Hibernate 4.3.X . You are using the hibernate4 `LocalSessionFactoryBean` which could well be why you are receiving the NoSuchMethodException - spring constructs the session factory bean with reflection and the API may have changed between v4 and 5.

Also I would try remove the reference to hibernate annotations, as per [this](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/ClarificationAboutAnnotationsAndEntityManager) it should no longer be necessary.